# How can you do two-way Dropbox <--> local folder syncing on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, data-synchronization, photos, dropbox

On my iPhone, I sync my camera photos with Dropbox, so that after I do a photo shoot all the photos are automatically uploaded to my laptop in the Dropbox 'Camera Uploads' folder - ready to sort, edit and delete as necessary.

I now need to be able to do two-way syncing with the iPhone, so that when I delete (or even modify) a photo on the computer, it's also deleted (or modified) from the iPhone's camera photos folder accordingly; this way I'm not left with dozens of 'dud' photos that I no longer want on my iPhone, despite having already deleting them on the laptop.

The official Dropbox mobile client doesn't allow two-way syncing, so until they introduce such a feature, this can only be possible via a third-party dropbox API-using client.

On Android, I could do this with [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync), with many features and full sync customization. Is there an equivalent Dropbox solution for this on iOS?

(I am aware of the idea that iCloud may do two-way syncing built-in, (though am not sure), but I'd like to be able to share the Camera Uploads folder with family members on Windows computers (and even linux), and so find Dropbox a much more multi-platform-friendly service to use for the syncing and collaborating, instead of the iCloud ecosystem.)

Comment: Have you tried using both iCloud and dropbox together? Maybe hard linking the folders... If you want 2 way sync for editing photos on your computer, iCloud will do it. Then you want the same pictures to be automatically shared, dropbox magic.

Comment: @Cawas I have tried to do this but iCloud is not syncing photo deletions BACK to the iPhone from the PC. I have asked about it as a follow-up question, here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115767/can-icloud-do-two-way-photo-syncing-deletion-between-the-iphone-and-a-pc

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Damn, some times apple suck hard and beyond comprehension! So, the final answer right now is: it can't be done. Get an android. One of many reasons I dropped iPhone.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I'm almost certain there's no equivalent Dropbox solution for this currently on iOS.

While I cannot give you a technical reason why two-way syncing on iOS is not possible, I can say that at a high level, the iOS platform is more *guarded* in terms of allowing developers to access certain capabilities of the device.

As you stated in your question, Android devices are capable of two-way synchronization through apps like Dropsync; this is because of the relatively more *open-ended* nature of the Android platform for both developers and users. To read more on why this is the case, read the 'Android Offers an Open Platform' section of [this article](http://lifehacker.com/ios-vs-android-your-best-arguments-1334921103).

To confirm, I contacted two customer representatives of two data-sync companies: Loom and SugarSync. I asked both reps the following question:

> Is possible for two-way synchronization of files between an iOS device and a computer? For example, if I sync pix from my iPhone to my iMac, and then edit/delete the pix on my computer, will the changes be reflected automatically on my iPhone?

Both times, the answer was:

> No, this is not possible due to the closed nature of the iOS platform.

If this capability is very important for your work, I would suggest migrating back to an Android device.

If you want/need to use your iPhone for this, and if you need a platform-independent solution (*i.e.*, you don't want to use iCloud), I'm afraid tedium is in your future. I would suggest that you keep a list of the photos as you edit/delete them on you computer, so that you know which photos have been updated and need to be manually re-download from Dropbox (or manually deleted) on your iPhone when you use it next.

Comment: I am impressed at that answer, thank you VERY much. I think what I'll do now is, investigate whether iCloud itself can do it (I'm sure it can, though I'm hoping to do the main syncing to a Windows computer), then chain together THAT (folder) with Dropbox. Dropbox can do two-way syncing (on e.g. Windows), and if iCloud can between the iPhone and a (windows) computer (maybe I can find some third-party Windows client to sync with the iCloud account if need be), then boom I can connect the two together and still achieve what I want to achieve. Heh. Boom.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to jailbreak, you can use [iFile](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/eu.heinelt.ifile) to two-way sync a folder in /var/mobile with a folder in Dropbox. It can't do background two-way sync, but you can do it manually.

Comment: If OP is willing to jailbreak, I think this is the best approach given his needs. I noticed you edited your answer to remove Backgrounder; does Backgrounder not work with iFile?

Comment: @bunting Backgrounder's development was stopped and it doesn't work in iOS 6+ so it's pretty useless now :( Still works on my trusty iPod touch 2nd-gen (stuck on iOS 4.2.1) but not with any recent hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I know [Documents by Readle](https://readdle.com/products/documents) supports two-way sync with Dropbox and other cloud services on iOS. I use it all the time sync books from my computer and iOS devices.